# git read only mirror repo that self updates

Tags: git, github, mirror

I would like to create on-premise git read-only repo mirror of a cloud git repo that could be used for CI and similar needs that do not involve committing changes back.

It seems creating git clone --mirror ... is the promising option - is there better?

The element I am struggling with is the updates. There is an obvious solution of making a cron job to update on an interval, but I hope there is something smarter that I can do easily.

I am wondering is it possible to hook a git fetch operation on (about to read event). With other words is it possible to hook in a git server detection of a request and make sure I fetch from the remote in the mirror before I respond.

Or I should just add notifications on the remote to listen to and update on them?

I am sorry, if this was answered, before - I am googling for a while now, without finding a decisive answer.

Comment: Ideally you can implement a hook in the repository which you are mirroring which will call out to your read-only mirror and cause it to update.  If your source repository is a self-hosted git repository, read about the `post-receive` hook.  For repositories hosted on github, bitbucket, etc, read about web hooks.

Comment: I would go the webhook route.

Comment: Another option, if you are the main author on this repository would be to push to multiple remotes at the same time by setting up two push urls: `git remote set-url --add --push origin <second url>` as explained in [this blog post](https://jigarius.com/blog/multiple-git-remote-repositories). After that `git push` will push to  both the cloud remote and the other url of your read-only repo mirror.